# How to compute full star or half star from a decimal value

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm looking at this star rating display in a ul list.
In this example, the value is 4.5 so the last half star is 'fa-star-half-alt'
Is there an easy way to easily modify this so that I can calulate the correct stars for a another decimal value (ex. 3.1)?

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline rating mb-0">
  <li class="list-inline-item mr-0"><i class="far fa-star amber-text"> </i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item mr-0"><i class="far fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item mr-0"><i class="far fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item mr-0"><i class="far fa-star amber-text"></i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><i class="far fa-star-half-alt amber-text"></i></li>
  <li class="list-inline-item"><p class="text-muted">4.5 (413)</p></li>
</ul>
```